# Rails: How to Handle State and City Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails (using 3.1) and am looking to have a URL that looks something like this:

domain.com/jobs/florida/orlando

I understand this falls outside of the typical route with an action and one id, so what is the best way to do this? Would this fall under nested routing?

More in depth - if someone hits the /jobs page, they would see a list of states. If they hit the /jobs/florida page, they'd see a list of cities. And finally if they hit the /jobs/florida/orlando, they would see a list of jobs open in Orlando.

What would my route look like? Should I be thinking about this URL structure another way? My primary motivation is SEO - these pages won't typically be viewed logged in users, just if they find the site through a search result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in your routes.rb file if you have a fixed depth

```
match 'jobs/:state/:city/:neighborhood' => "Jobs#show"
```

In your show action you can then look for params[:state], params[:city], etc, and load the appropriate jobs.

Comment: All three answers given so far have been excellent, I chose this one for its simplicity. Thanks for helping a rails noob!

Comment: From 3 answers you've chosen one that doesn't address your question - to match `/jobs`, and `/jobs/florida`. This one route matches only full path.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [dynamic segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) from rails guide. Basically your example should have route like this:

```
get "/jobs(/:state(/:city))", :to => "jobs#index"
```

and in your `index` action in `JobsController` you check if your have state selected and city selected. If yes, then you display list of jobs from that region, if no, then you display deeper level of nesting than your current level.

If it would help, you can spread this route to 3 different:

```
get "/jobs", :to => "jobs#index_without_state"
get "/jobs/:state", :to => "jobs#index_without_city"
get "/jobs/:state/:city", :to => "jobs#index"
```

or however you feel, but I think it's over-engineered and first proposition should not be much harder to implement (especially when you can extract some logic to before_filters if you have specific segment from route)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it like:

```
resources :jobs do
  collection do
    constraints :state_id => /[a-z\-]+/ do
      get ':state_id' => 'states#show', :as => :state
      get ':state_id/:city_id' => 'cities#show', :as => :city
    end
  end
end
```

- `/jobs` will go to `jobs#index`

You mustn't have numbers in your city/state names!

- `/jobs/florida`   goes to `states#show` with state_id = florida
- `/jobs/new-york`  goes to `states#show` with state_id = new-york
- `/jobs/florida/orlando` goes to `cities#show` with city_id = orlando

Now comes the fun part! You can use slugs for your jobs as well:

- `/jobs/1234-experienced-senior-programmer` goes to `jobs#show` with `1234-experienced-senior-programmer` as id, just do `params[:id].to_i` and you will get the id 1234 :)

The not-so-fun part:

collection methods like `/jobs/new` won't work anymore - you could change this by adding a quantifier like `:state_id => /[a-z\-]{4,}/` so
this requires state names to have at least 4 characters and all 3-letter collection methods like `new` will be passed to jobs controller as usual

the generated routes:

```
state_jobs GET    /jobs/:state_id(.:format)     {:controller=>"states", :state_id=>/[a-z\-]+/, :action=>"show"}
 city_jobs GET    /jobs/:state_id/:city_id(.:format) {:controller=>"cities", :state_id=>/[a-z\-]+/, :action=>"show"}
      jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)               {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"index"}
           POST   /jobs(.:format)               {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"create"}
   new_job GET    /jobs/new(.:format)           {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"new"}
  edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format)      {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"edit"}
       job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"show"}
           PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"update"}
           DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"jobs", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. This is huge!